# ASP.net simple design question

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dom

I have this in a repeater:

```
<div class="vote-wrapper">
    <asp:hyperlink runat="server" CssClass="s dislike-button" ID="CommentVoteDown" />                        
    <div class="vote-total-bad">
        23
    </div>
    <asp:hyperlink runat="server" CssClass="s like-button" ID="CommentVoteUp" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

This is repeated (obviously!).  Due to my project settings, I've made it no generate unique ID's, and manage it all myself, the reason for this is that it makes calling references to DOM elements in external JS files a lot easier.

The ID's come out as duplicates, all are `CommentVoteDown` and `CommentVoteUp`.  What I want to do, is make them read as:

```
CommentVoteUp124
CommentVoteDown124
```

Where the number afterwards represents the ID of the comment it is associated with.

I try doing:

```
 UV.Attributes["ID"] += ThisComment.ID;
```

and

```
UV.Attributes.Add("ID", "CommentVoteUp" + ThisComment.ID);
```

But these just add second keys to the HTML element.  How can I name them so I can reference them in Jquery?

Comment: do these buttons do a postback of any kind?

Comment: Yeah, unless you're posting back, using controls instead of regular html anchors doesn't give you anything.  Might make it run a little slower given you `new` an object for each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you do something like

```
<asp:hyperlink runat="server" CssClass="s dislike-button" 
                ID='<%# "CommentVoteDown" + Eval("ID") %>' />
```

Answer (score 2):

Won't this work?

```
UV.ID += ThisComment.ID;
```

---

Unless you're doing a postback you don't have to use asp.net server controls and might be better off with clean and simple html:

```
<% Comment comment = Container.DataItem as Comment %>
<div class="vote-wrapper">
    <a class="s dislike-button" ID="CommentVoteDown<%=comment.ID %>" />                        
    <div class="vote-total-bad">
        23
    </div>
    <a class="s like-button" ID="CommentVoteUp<%=comment.ID %>" />                        
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

of just use the classes and find the id off the wrapping container with jQuery

```
<% Comment comment = Container.DataItem as Comment %>
<div id="CommentVoteUp<%=comment.ID %>" class="vote-wrapper">
    <a class="s dislike-button" />                        
    <div class="vote-total-bad">
        23
    </div>
    <a class="s like-button" />                        
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and then using jQuery you can find the id from the scope of the vote up/ down `<a>` tag using this:

```
$(".like-button").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest(".vote-wrapper").attr("id");
});

$(".dislike-button").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).closest(".vote-wrapper").attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add it to the cssclass on the element? This may make it a lot easier.

CommentVoteUp.Attributes["class"] = "[add your class name here]";